# Rails: App partial is not responding normally in production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production, partials

I have a problem in production, code in my partial is not working as expected on heroku.

In my website I have a quiz in which the users Receive a question with answers. Upon getting the question right or wrong this renders a partial for the users like this:

```
<%= link_to "Answer1", correct_answer_courses_path,:remote => true,:class=>"btn btn-warning"  %>
```

correct_answer.js.erb

```
$("#correct_answer").html("<%= j render partial: "beginnercourse/correct", locals: {questionnumber: @questionnumber, coursetitle: @coursetitle, routenumber: @routenumber} %>");
```

The controller

```
def beginnercourse_q1
  def correct_answer
    @questionnumber = 1
    @routenumber = @questionnumber + 1
    @coursetitle = "beginnerscourse"
    respond_to do |format|               
      format.js
    end        
  end 

  def false_answer
    @questionnumber = 1
    @routenumber = @questionnumber + 1
    @coursetitle = "beginnerscourse"
    respond_to do |format|               
      format.js
    end        
  end    
end
```

And this will render the partial, located in /beginnercourse/_correct.html.erb

```
   <div>
     <h2> Correct!</h2>

      <% if $current_course.send("claimedreward#{questionnumber}") == false%>
        <h2><span class = "yellowtext">Well Done, + 100 tradepoints</span></h2>
        <% current_user.update_attributes(tradepoints: (current_user.tradepoints + 100)) %>
        <% $current_course.update_attributes("claimedreward#{questionnumber}" => true) %>

        <%= link_to "Next", "/courses/#{coursetitle}_q#{routenumber}",class:"btn btn-warning" %>
        <%= render 'layouts/coursefooter' %>


      <% else %>
        <h2><span class = "redtext">Points were already rewarded</span></h2>  

        <%= link_to "Next", "/courses/#{coursetitle}_q#{routenumber}",class:"btn btn-warning" %>
        <%= render 'layouts/coursefooter' %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

In development this all works normally but on Heroku there are a couple of issues:

- When clicking next, it goes to the wrong question (doesn't get the new @routenumber? from the controller). about 30% of the times (seems really random)
- Saying that the reward was already given while it was not . (also about 1/5th of the times)

My heroku log. (heroku trying to load question 4 3times instead of going to question 5): https://gist.github.com/Mixelated/41e78b7fceae213541d95fad1d3c1908

I have been stuck on it for a while now and can't seem to find out why it doesn't run stable on Heroku. I would appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Just found out an error at: `$("#correct_answer").html("<%= j render partial: "beginnercourse/correct", locals: {questionnumber: @questionnumber, coursetitle: @coursetitle, routenumber: @routenumber} %>");`, the partial name `beginnercourse/correct` should be wrapped in single quotes instead of double quotes!

Comment: Hey thanks, changed it but still the same issue

Comment: Could be because you are using instance variables instead of local variables. I.e remove the @ sign.

Comment: @HieuPham why single quote? its under <% and %>. inside an erb template file. Its irrelevant if its single or double quoted.

Comment: @M1xelated, I'm concerned with that $current_course global variable. I think you miss some important information like the controller that renders that link and the route.rb for it.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I am wrong, but I can see that you always set the questionnumber to be 1 initially, so the next will always redirect you to the second question. Is it possible that you need to send the current question number as parameter to the controller or keep the value across the requests somehow?